# How to remove every third element from a linked list recursively?

Tags: java

I would like to iterate over a linked list and remove every third element recursively.

If the end of the list is reached, I do the same call on those elements which are left in the linked list. I'm doing that until only one element is left in the linked list.

My solution which does not work as expected:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

    public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int randomNumber = (int )(Math.random() * 50 + 1);
        List<Integer> testList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= randomNumber; i++)
        {
            testList.add(i);
        }
    }
        public void removeElements(List testList)
        {
           for(int i = 0; i < testList.size();i++){
                if(i % 3 == 0){
                    testList.remove(i);
                }
            }
            if(testList.isEmpty()){
                return;
            }
            removeElements(testList-1);
        }
 }
```

Comment: So you are removing every 3rd element recursively until only 1 is left, BUT what will you remove on the penultimate recursive call when there are 2 elements in the list and you are supposed to remove every 3rd ? Maybe base case should be if list size is 2 not 1 ?

Comment: I have added an answer with explanation of what is done. Check below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're doing it recursively, then there's no need to iterate. Simplify the problem down to one iteration and apply it to the current state, and then the rest of the list. There doesn't seem to be a node class, so it has to be done with indexes.

Removing the third element means keeping the current two elements and removing the one after them. We also have to take into account that the list will 'shift' when we remove one, so we don't have to advance forward after removing. The next 'current' will be the same index as the index we removed from.

```
public void removeElements(List list, int current) {
   int removeIndex = current + 2;     // remove the third element
   if (removeIndex >= list.size())    // if there isn't one, stop
      return;

   list.remove(removeIndex);          // if there is one, remove it
   removeElements(list, removeIndex); // continue with the rest of the list
}
```

To avoid always having to prep the method, you can write a second one that does it for you:

```
public void removeElements(List list) {
   removeElements(list, 0);
}
```

Ex:

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(4);
list.add(5);
list.add(6);
list.add(7);
list.add(8);
list.add(9);
list.add(10);

removeElements(list);

for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++)
   System.out.println(list.get(x));

// output: 1 2 4 5 7 8 10
```

Since you updated which nth item you want to remove, this can easily be changed by modifying the value that is added to the current index:

```
public void removeElements(List list, int current, int n) {
   int removeIndex = current + n - 1;    // remove the nth element
   if (removeIndex >= list.size())       // if there isn't one, stop
      return;

   list.remove(removeIndex);             // if there is one, remove it
   removeElements(list, removeIndex, n); // continue with the rest of the list
}

public void removeEverySecond(List list) {
   removeElements(list, 0, 2);
}

public void removeEveryThird(List list) {
   removeElements(list, 0, 3);
}

// etc.
```

Comment: If you are removing white iterating over it, doesn't the list.size() changes its evaluation ?

Comment: @sad_cat yes, but it's accurate each time it's tested. we stop as soon as there's nothing left to remove.

Comment: But the OP wants to remove every 3rd element

Answer (score 0):

You are removing items from the list you are iterating over. That makes it vulnerable. The list gets smaller while the iteration gets bigger. This leads to IndexOutOfBounds like errors.

It is probably a better idea to make a copy of the list and remove stuff from the copy based on iteration over the orinal and then return the reduced copy.

Answer (score 0):

> remove every third element recursively.

and the code

```
if(i % 3 == 0){
                testList.remove(i);
            }
```

it looks like the code removes **first** and then every third. Is really what are you expecting? However if you fix it then you will face the issue @GCP has mentioned

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));

        removeRecursive(list);

        System.out.println("The elements that remained in the list are: " + list);

    }


   public static void removeRecursive(List<Integer> list){

        if (list.size() < 3)
           return;

       for (int i = 2; i < list.size(); i += 2) {
           System.out.println("Removing element " + list.remove(i) + " from the list.");
       }

       removeRecursive(list);

   }
}
```

OK, so what I do here is:

I declare LinkedList of Integers from 1 to 10, I call the recursive method, and printout the final content of the list after recursive method finishes its job.

**IN RECURSIVE METHOD:**

We take LinkedList of Integers as an argument, our base case is if list.size() is less than 3 (since we need to remove every 3rd element), because if list has less than 3 elements we can't remove the 3rd one (obviously), then we loop from element at index 2 (third element) and remove it, we also increase our **i** for 2 every time loop ends so we keep deleting every 3rd element until we reach the end of the list. Then we call our recursive method again and we pass our LinkedList with all the remaining elements, eventually when list size is less than 3 our recursive method is done. We then go back to main and print out the elements that remained in the list after everything is finished.

Output for list of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10:

Removing element 3 from the list.

Removing element 6 from the list.

Removing element 9 from the list.

Removing element 4 from the list.

Removing element 8 from the list.

Removing element 5 from the list.

Removing element 7 from the list.

Removing element 10 from the list.

The elements that remained in the list are: [1, 2]